# Prepared Statement Procedural

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I need to convert the following into a procedural prepared statement. I'm having hard time with this. I was able to do that for the registration, but not for the login. Please help me convert the following using Procedural Prepared Statement.

```
if (empty($errors)) {
    $q = "SELECT first_name, user_id FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";
    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return array(true, $row);
    } else { //If credentials are incorrect
        $errors[] = 'The email or password is incorrect. Please try again';
    }
} // End of Empty Errors
```

Comment: It already is procedural by the looks of it.

Comment: [**Read the manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you explain what it meant by procedural?

Comment: I want to prevent injection. How do I covert this to use prepared statement?

Comment: You have to learn about prepared statements first, read the manual. You can't expect us to teach you all of that. Also, as far as I'm concerned prepared statements work with `MySQLi` and `PDO`, which are `object-oriented`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking. But if you would like to change your code to use a [`prepared statement`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) this should work:

```
// connect to server 
$con = new mysqli('<hostname>','<username>','<password>','<database>');
if(empty($errors)) {
  // create a prepared statement
  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT first_name, user_id FROM users 
                         WHERE email = ? && pass=SHA1(?)");
  // bind parameters
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $e, $p);
  // bind result
  $first_name = '';
  $user_id = 0;
  $stmt->bind_result($first_name, $user_id);
  // execute the query
  $stmt->execute();
  // store result so we can call `$num_rows` immediately
  $stmt->store_result();
  if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
     // fetch the data
     $stmt->fetch();
     return array(true, array($user_id, $first_name));
  } else {
     errors[] = 'The email or password is incorrect. Please try again';
  }
}
```

Comment: You or I would assume so, but it's not quite procedural, it's OOP. I tried to explain in my comment above that prepared statements work with OOP libs. Guess OP doesn't like OOP.

Comment: Ooops, I just thought the question was about using prepared statements.

Comment: Keep it, it might englighten OP to start using OOP, it's not like it's bad to include a small class in a procedural (d'oh) code.